# How to hide field input in FastAPI swagger UI but still accessible if user choose to input it?

Tags: python, fastapi

How do i hide a field in the FastAPI UI, yet i am able to pass in information if needed?
I tried adding '_' to the field name and added alias to map it, however the alias input is not registered.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

app = FastAPI()

class Subject(BaseModel):
    score: int
    _difficulty: str = Field('low', alias='difficulty')
```

```
Input data = {'score'= 70, 'difficulty'='high'}
```

When I post the above data, `Subject._difficulty` still show as `'low'`

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1708 - in particular, for Pydantic models, using `schema_extra` to remove fields from documentation: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#schema-customization